# How can I update a model attribute in JSP from the AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a JSP page like this

```html
<li id="notifications">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${empty alerts}">
          <p class="text-default">There are no Service Reminders at this time</p>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
           <c:forEach items="${alerts}" var="alert">
            <p class="text-default">${alert.serviceItemDescription}</p>
             </c:forEach>
          <button onclick="clearNotifications()" id="clearButton" >clear
       </button>
         </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</li>
```

1. The attribute {alerts} which is a list.
2. I want to update this existing list based on the AJAX response I'm getting from this below code.
3. AJAX "result" is a new List to iterate. How can I update the existing model attribute "alerts" by this new value 'result' from below code to update the 'list' tag element ?

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function clearNotifications() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/clearNotifications/" + $ {
          bike.id
        },
        headers: {
          "Accept": "text/html,application/json"
        },
        success: function(result) {
          $("#notifications").html(result);
        }
      }
    });
} </script>
```

Comment: Yes, you can update it as you have indicated, but the response you want from your server is `HTML` not json.  The HTML being the `select/options` html tag and data

Comment: You should send json data from server end and update list in jsp via looping. before looping parse that json string.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I changed the dataType:  to "html".I'm getting the empty list from AJAX response, in my case so it has to display whats there in the <when> condition tag, but when I click on the button it is displaying [] symbol on the screen instead of what is in <when> condition tag. Am I doing something wrong/ How can I achieve it?

Comment: The when tag is being done on the initial load of the page (serverside) - when you are doing ajax, you are dealing on the client side, no more `jsp` tags will be evaluated.  The result that you are getting back should be pure HTML (in this case) and so the dom can be updated with pure HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this,

In your Jsp, change the `li` as follows,

```
<li id="notifications">

</li>
```

You can play with js, specially into the ajax,

This is for page loads initially,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alerts = ${alerts};
        populateNotification();
    });

function populateNotification(alerts)   {

    for(var i=0; i<alerts.length; i++){
        $("#notifications").html("<p class='text-default'>${alerts[i].serviceItemDescription}</p>");        
    }

    $("#notifications").append("<button onclick='clearNotifications()' id='clearButton' >clear     </button>");
}
```

This is for Ajax calls,

```
function clearNotifications() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/clearNotifications/" + $ {
          bike.id
        },
        headers: {
          "Accept": "text/html,application/json"
        },
        success: function(result) {
          //$("#notifications").html(result);
          alerts = result;
          populateNotification(alerts);
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Desing.. Actually I have modified the return value "result" to be boolean value in the method which AJAX calling to check if the POST is successful or not, so the below code worked for me, I haven't tried yours but looks like yours is more elegant solution if I'm returning a List in the "result". just reloaded the List tag with id notifications.
                    `success: function (result) {
                        if (result === true) {
                            $("#notifications").load(" #notifications"); } }`